# Android MVVM: databinding value is not set from MediatorLiveData in particular situation

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-mvvm

When setting a value to MediatorLiveData that reacts to a source added in the constructor of a viewModel or activity onCreate observer in the ViewModel , like this for example:

```
    showingMethodLiveData.addSource(stateChangeLiveData) {
        when (it) {
                    ConfigurationState.CURRENT -> showingMethodLiveData.value = commMethod[it]

                    ConfigurationState.PENDING -> showingMethodLiveData.value = commMethod[it]
                }
            }
```

The value isn't set to the observing view, although the set method is called.
I can work around this by either adding the source in onStart (which creates other problems of registering observer more than once), or using postValue instead of setValue.

The debug of setValue method leads me to following code, where there is an interesting comment that tells the story, the method returns without setting the value to the binded view.

in androidx.databinding package of lifecycle dependency:
class ViewDataBinding:

```
    private void handleFieldChange(int mLocalFieldId, Object object, int fieldId) {
            if (mInLiveDataRegisterObserver) {
                // We're in LiveData registration, which always results in a field change
                // that we can ignore. The value will be read immediately after anyway, so
                // there is no need to be dirty.
                return;
            }
            boolean result = onFieldChange(mLocalFieldId, object, fieldId);
            if (result) {
                requestRebind();
            }
        }
```

The value is not set afterwards either, but only when the mediatorlivedata is invoked again by change in it's source.
Why this situation occurs?
Thank you for the help
PS
I think it may be an android library bug

Answer (score 0):

The use of Mediatorlivedata is to compare two values and then provide a result.
If you want to change the value of a variable, you can simply use MutableLiveData and to assign a new value, write `variableName.value = newValue`

Answer (score 0):

Should be even easier to achieve like this:

```
val showingMethodLiveData = Transformations.map(stateChangeLiveData) { commMethod[it] }
```